Runtime speeds of program not consistent when changing the speed unit
I am writting that program that computes prefix sum and scan. I want to compute my runtime in milliseconds, but something does not seem right when I test it.
double executeFunction(double *arr, int size, void (*function)(double *, int)) {
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    function(arr, size);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    return (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000.0;
}

This is the function I have to compute time in milliseconds
double executeFunction(double *arr, int size, void (*function)(double *, int)) {
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    function(arr, size);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    return (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
}

When I print the time I use
double cpu_time_used = executeFunction(arr, size, function);
printf("Time taken: %f \n", cpu_time_used);

This is the function I have to compute time in seconds (just the division on the final line.
my output for the ms code is
Size: 1000000
Function: prefixSum
Input file: /dev/null
Time taken: 1.861000 ms
Output file: /dev/null

my output for the seconds code is
Size: 1000000
Function: prefixSum
Input file: /dev/null
Time taken: 0.004642 seconds
Output file: /dev/null

Is there a reason that the times are so far off from eachother.
I tried to run sizes on various sizes but didn't get any notable results. I am expecting that milliseconds is ~1000 times more than seconds.

The first rule of benchmarking is to always do it on an optimized build. Secondly, you have to remember that you're not alone on your system, there are many other processes competing for the same resources. And don't do only a single test, do multiple (the more the better) and calculate the average of all runs.

1.861ms and 4.642ms is not far from each other. In a single run, such things may happen. Run your your function 1000 or more times and calculate average time.

The first function uses the wrong divisor.

Note that the code you show for printing the time doesn't produce either of the outputs you show.
